Валидация ИНН: преобразование номера ИНН, начинающегося с 0
При регистрации пользователя у меня есть поле ввода ИНН
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при вводе в поле ИНН, номер ИНН начинающийся с 0, 0 обрезается и инн становиться не валидиным
Я попробовал задать инпуту type="text", чтобы можно было валидировать инн, а перед отправкой на бэк преобразовывать в число, но 0 в начале номера инн все равно обрезается, не знаю как это пофиксить

Очевидное решение — не преобразовывать в число.

ИНН это не число, а строка из 12 цифр

Берете введенный инн, копируете его в отдельную переменную, разбиваете на группы, нужное преобразовываете в числа  считаете. Если ок, сохраняете исходный инн

не надо отправлять ИНН как число, надо отправлять как строку....как раз из-за нулей
